# Python path when importing can't be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, path, python-import

This, I presume, is a fairly common question, but I can't seem to import my Python module.

This code runs absolutely fine on my Ubuntu machine back home, but doesn't seem to work on my Windows machine at work. Which leads me to believe it boils down to either a difference in how Python works on Windows compared to a *nix-system, or that it handles modules completely different.

From my understanding modules should be loaded based on the `sys.path`, as per every other question regarding the issue and the reading I've done.

However, I've got a simple project like this:

```
DataStructures
├───.git
└───Python
    ├───DoublyLinkedListStarter.py
    └───LinkedLists
        ├───Doubly.py
        └──────LinkedNodes
               └───DoublyLinkedNode.py
```

If I navigate to `Python/` and run `python .\DoublyLinkedListStart.py`, I'm getting a module error in `Doubly.py`:

> Unable to import module LinkedNodes

The code is very basic, it's a Python implementation of a Doubly linked list, where `DoublyLinkedListStarter` imports `Doubly` which implements the body Linked List, and imports the  `DoublyLinkedNode`.

`DoublyLinkedListStart.py`:

```
from LinkedList import Doubly
```

`Doubly.py`:

```
from LinkedNodes import DoublyLinkedNode
```

Again, this worked absolutely fine on my Ubuntu machine before I pushed it up to git and pulled it down on my windows machine.

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where you are importing the `LinkedNodes` module?

Comment: @Andreas Done. As mentioned before, it's super basic. It **should** work

Comment: Have you tried putting an ´__init__.py´ file (which is empty otherwise) in the starting folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from LinkedLists.LinkedNodes import DoublyLinkedNode
```

But this is an issue with the PYTHONPATH system variable.  Another way to do it is to add it to the PYTHONPATH system variable:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;LinkedLists\LinkedNodes
python .\DoublyLinkedListStart.py
```

You have to do that every time you open the command line.

The path python is using can be accessed from within a python script with sys.path, which is a list.  That gives another way to add import paths:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("LinkedLists")
from LinkedNodes import DoublyLinkedNode
```

You got options ;)

Comment: Strange. I mean, that would sort it. But it seems like a hack more than the correct way of doing this. Surely I shouldn't have to add a relative path from where I run `DoublyLinkedListStarter.py` from? Python should be clever enough to look at where the `cursor` or to somehow calculate where the file is and evaluate the path to the module based on the current directory?

Comment: I edited the answer, the first example I give is the best way to do imports.  The root is the directory that python is being executed from and you must list the full path of directories to what you're trying to import.  Otherwise you are stuck only being able to import from the directories below the one that particular script is located in and you can't import from 'sibling' directories in the tree.  It is not possible to go "up one level."

Comment: But as I mention, and as you can see in my post, `DoublyLinkedListStart` doesn't reference the nodes, only the `Doubly.py`. So surely, if `Doubly.py` imports `DoublyLinkedNodes.py`, which is in its folder, it should be fine? 
It's not like I'm doing all the imports in the start file.

Comment: Try this:
    from .LinkedNodes import DoublyLinkedNode